# One controller not responding to before_action or skip_before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following before_actions in my ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper
  before_action :logged_in_user
  before_action :admin_user
  private

    # Confirms a logged-in user.
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        store_location
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end

    # Confirms an admin user.
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

And I have skip_before_actions in my PostsController:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :logged_in_user,    except: [:new, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  skip_before_action :admin_user,     except: [:new, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :find_post,      only: [:edit, :update, :show, :delete]
```

The find_post action works perfectly, and the method is in that controller. I want to be able to access `posts#index` and `posts#show` without logging in or being an admin, but everything I try, it won't skip those actions, and I'm redirected to log in. It's working in my other controllers. I worked around the index by routing to `static_pages#home` and defining that action to `render posts/index` with `skip_before_action` in the static_pages controller. In a previous attempt, I tried not putting the before action in `ApplicationController`, and just calling before_action in `PostsController` and `UsersController` when I need it, but `PostsController` wasn't doing that either. I wrote a test action to just redirect_to in `PostsController` and tried calling `before_action :test_action` on everything, and it wouldn't do that either. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you put this up on Github somewhere? It sounds like you're doing everything correctly, there's something you're probably missing. 

Anecdotal: I'd consider it a code smell to use skip_before_action to omit a callback that you set for all controllers in your application. I'd personally remove those callbacks from `ApplicationController` and just call the callbacks when you need it. You'll likely hurt yourself in the long run.

Comment: I've got it on bitbucket... I'm just trying to learn right now. I know, the skip action is messy, but I was desperate to find solutions...git@bitbucket.org:kylealm/rails-sample-app.git

Comment: you need to make it public (I'm sure that's a thing inside Bitbucket), or hop on over to Github

Comment: Alright, it should be better now?

Comment: It is! Can you make sure that your code is up-to-date as well? I'm not seeing the changes you made in posts_controller.rb :)

Comment: I just tried another commit and push, but it says it's up to date. Last push was "add before actions"

Comment: I'm not able to pull it down right now (I'm mobile) but I was able to look at your controllers. Like I alluded to, in almost every controller you're skipping the filters you define in application_controller.rb — I would only add those filters when you need them, not remove them when you don't need them. I think once you've cleaned up the logic you'll be able to pinpoint where the issue is occurring. You're not doing anything that would interfere with how callbacks work (it's an otherwise hard thing to do).

Comment: Also, the posts_controller.rb code, as it is, doesn't have any skip_before_action callbacks — answering your initial question as to why it continues to respond to those actions.

Comment: Can you post your controller code.  Also can what happens when you try:`skip_before_action :logged_in_user,    only: [:index, :show]
  skip_before_action :admin_user,     only: [:index, :show]`

Answer (score 0):

According OOP, logged_in_user method is **private** so that in PostsController, skip_before_action doesn't find this method.

Answer (score 0):

After Josh Brody took a look at my git file, I found the problem... apologies to everyone, but it seems there was an issue with my IDE instead. It wasn't properly saving my posts controller. Reboot the computer, and everything worked. I went back and switched the logic to instead use before_action. Ha, wasted six hours of my day banging my head against the computer thinking it was my code. Good learning experience.